# How to calculate VPC in glmer?

Tags: r, variance, regression-coefficients, partitioning

For a specific analysis I want to calculate the *variance partition coefficient* (VPC). I am using the following formula:

```
 test <- glmer(SocEenz ~ Herkomst + OuderPersoon + statusscore14 + M_SpoWeek + 
             (1|POSCODN), data = dataScaled, family = binomial)

> summary(test)
     Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
       Family: binomial  ( logit )
       Formula: SocEenz ~ Herkomst + OuderPersoon + statusscore14 + M_SpoWeek +  (1 | POSCODN)
       Data: dataScaled

   AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  43707.5  43757.9 -21847.8  43695.5    32684 

Scaled residuals: 
   Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
 -1.3263 -0.8378 -0.7164  1.1263  2.4788 

  Random effects:
 Groups  Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 POSCODN (Intercept) 0.007148 0.08455 
 Number of obs: 32690, groups:  POSCODN, 173

Fixed effects:
          Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
 (Intercept)   -0.56437    0.01798 -31.387  < 2e-16 ***
 Herkomst1      0.49571    0.02980  16.633  < 2e-16 ***
 OuderPersoon1  0.29911    0.02433  12.295  < 2e-16 ***
 statusscore14 -0.09900    0.01353  -7.316 2.56e-13 ***
 M_SpoWeek     -0.08658    0.01225  -7.067 1.58e-12 ***

 Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

   Correlation of Fixed Effects:
        (Intr) Hrkms1 OdrPr1 stts14
Herkomst1   -0.436                     
OuderPersn1 -0.553  0.168              
statusscr14 -0.068  0.233  0.013       
M_SpoWeek   -0.044 -0.029  0.138 -0.034
```

Because I only have information in the outcome about POSCODN at random effects I am not sure how to calculate the VPC. How can I get an extra row there with information about residuals. For example:

```
  Random effects:
 Groups  Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 POSCODN (Intercept) 0.007148 0.08455 
 Residual             258.357 16.0735 
 Number of obs: 32690, groups:  POSCODN, 173
```

Or do you have other suggestions how to calculate the VPC?

Comment: it would help to give more information (formula/definition/link/etc.) about the variance partition coefficient.  Since this is a binomial model, there isn't a trivial form for "residual variance"; see Nakagawa & Schielzeth. “A General and Simple Method for Obtaining R2 from Generalized Linear Mixed-Effects Models.” Methods in Ecology and Evolution 4(2) (2013): 133–42. doi:10.1111/j.2041-210x.2012.00261.x  and “Repeatability for Gaussian and Non-Gaussian Data: A Practical Guide for Biologists.” Biol Reviews 85(4) (2010): 935–56. doi:10.1111/j.1469-185X.2010.00141.x.

Comment: also `sem.model.fits` in https://github.com/jslefche/piecewiseSEM/